# A DLL with WinForms that can be launched from A main app

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

I have created a C# DLL that has some forms in it.  ( I needed it to be a DLL, not a Windows Application.)
How can I run it as a Windows App? Should I create another app and load it? How? What do I need to learn to do that?
please let me know if I should explain more about my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using VS 2008:

First, create a Windows Forms Application project.  You can delete the default form that's created (Form1.cs) if you don't plan to use it.

In the Solution Explorer, right-click on the **References** and select **Add Reference**.  This is the point where you add your custom designed C# DLL.

Now open Program.cs, and in make the following change:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ****your DLL namespace here****
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new [****your startup form (from the DLL) here****]);
        }
    }
}
```

If the DLL contains disconnected forms, you'll probably need to add a class in the winforms project to coordinate the forms behavior.

Comment: " You can delete the default form that's created (Form1.cs) if you don't plan to use it."
...nice, I did not like to have a dummy form that I am not actually using it.

Answer (score 4):

You can add forms to your DLL, then make a public static function in the DLL that calls `Application.Run` with a form.

You can then call this public static method from a C# Application project (after adding a reference to the DLL).

Comment: so In my new C# App, I should have a dummy form that all it does is a call to that public static function in my DLL, right?
I want This new C# to be nothing more than a wrapper to run that DLL

Comment: No, in the new app in the program.cs replace the `Application.Run(new Form1());` with `Application.Run(new MyDllNamespace.MyDllMainForm());`

Do not forget to add a reference to the dll in your project references.

Answer (score 4):

You can launch it with [RunDll32](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/rundll32.htm) however you may need to tweek the dll a bit before it will work. You may need to put a `Application.Run` in the entry point. this way you do not need to compile another entire application to use it.

the below code is untested but I think it should work.

```
public static void myDllEntryPoint()
{
     Application.run(new MyFormInDll());   
}
```

Run your application as

```
rundll32.exe myDll.dll,myDllEntryPoint
```

Comment: cool, but this is my need: having kind of a C# exe application that all it does is being a wrapper for that DLL to show it.

Comment: Than I would go with SLaks answer.

Answer (score 2):

In VS2022 (.NET 6.0):

1. Set your DLL project to be a Class Library in it's Properties.
2. Right click on your EXE project, and add a Project Reference.
3. Choose the one in that list.

To open the form when already initialized:

```cs
DLLProject.FormClass myForm = new DLLProject.FormClass();
myForm.Show(); // or myForm.ShowDialog(), whichever suits you best
```

To open the form when not initialized (in Program.cs):

```
Application.Run(new DLLProject.FormClass());
```

Remember to delete the Program.cs in the DLL project, otherwise it won't compile.