# Opening a windows form with a DLL

Tags: visual-c++

I have made a DLL which is supposed to attach onto my process. In the DLL, I have a form called Form1.

I also have a cpp file. Here is what's in it:

```
void Main() {

}



BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
{
    DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hinstDLL);
    CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Main, 0, 0, 0);

}
else

    return 1;
}
```

Obviously, this is just attaching to the process. How would I make it so that Form1 opens in Main?

Sorry, I'm a newbie at this.

Thanks!

Comment: Bump? I really need help

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822326/a-dll-with-winforms-that-can-be-launched-from-a-main-app